# How to set multiple permission Scopes using SpotifyAPI-NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, spotify

I am using [SpotifyAPI-Net](https://johnnycrazy.github.io/SpotifyAPI-NET/) to build a personal project messing around with the Spotify web API.

What I am specifically trying to do is build a web page that can search Spotify, and then you can select from the search results to stream the selected song/album/whatever to one of your active connected devices. So I need a session with the "UserReadPlaybackState" Scope to read devices, but I will also need the "UserModifyPlaybackState" Scope to actully start playing my selected track on the selected device. But I can't figure out how to give my application more than a single Scope of permissions.

This is what my authentication looks like:

```
            auth = new AutorizationCodeAuth()
        {
            ClientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost",
            //How many permissions we need?
            Scope = Scope.UserReadPlaybackState,
        };
```

I've tried putting multiple Scopes together with +, or commas, but it doesn't seem to like any of those. Am I just missing something in the documentation?

Comment: Have you tried joining them with spaces?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my own question on the developer's respository [here](https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET/issues/207):

The answer is to use | characters to delimit multiple scopes, like

```
     WebAPIFactory webApiFactory = new WebAPIFactory( 
     "http://localhost", 
     8000, 
     "26d287105e31491889f3cd293d85bfea", 
     Scope.UserReadPrivate | Scope.UserReadEmail | Scope.PlaylistReadPrivate | Scope.UserLibraryRead | 
     Scope.UserReadPrivate | Scope.UserFollowRead | Scope.UserReadBirthdate | Scope.UserTopRead | Scope.PlaylistReadCollaborative | 
     Scope.UserReadRecentlyPlayed | Scope.UserReadPlaybackState | Scope.UserModifyPlaybackState);
```